# Дополнительный ajax запрос в parse

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

Имеется примерно 1500 моделей, прилетающих с сервера.

При fetch'e я в ф-ции `parse` пропускаю каждую модель через бьютификатор, потому что прилетающие, например, даты в таком формате - `2000-10-10`, - а нужно отображать в привычном, - `10.10.2000`.

Так же есть и другие преобразования.

Всё работало замечательно до момента, пока не встала необходимость грузить с сервера словарь. Дело в том, что в приходящих данных появилось дополнительное поле с айдишником. Айдишник соответствует индексу в словаре. Пользователям нельзя выводить айдишник, а нужно выводить текст. Поэтому нужно загрузить словарь и смаппить айдишники с текстовым значением, внести в модель и потом уже выводить.

До появления словаря структура в `parse` была такая:

```
parse: function(response) {
    _.each(response['elems'], function(v) {
    ...
    });
    return response['elems'];
}
```

Все было отлично, ничего не лагало на 1500 моделях.

Для загрузки словаря решил пойти впрямую и сделал:

```
parse: function(response) {
    var that = this; //Сохраняем указатель в коллекции
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "/returnDictToMe/",
        success: function(d, r) {
          _.each(response['elems'], function(v) {
          ...//Маппим словарь тут
          });
          that.add(response['elems']); //После преобразования, добавляем все модели в коллекцию
        }
    });
```

И вот тут жуткие лаги. Страница просто вешается и ничего не выводит. Вопрос: почему?
Вопрос 2: как сделать подгрузку словаря в parse правильно?

Есть вариант [изменить sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674238/backbone-model-ajax-request-in-parse-override) и вызывать там один запрос за другим, но этот вариант для меня плох, потому что есть много других страниц, где никакие словари не грузятся.

Какие есть мысли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вопрос: почему?

Тут могут быть варианты. Мне кажется, это из-за того, что словарь большой и на его загрузку требуется время. А до тех пор, пока словарь не загружен -- коллекция остается пустой и интерфейс не обновляется. А еще, проблема может быть в не эффективном отображении ID на текст (увы, код отображения вы не привели).

Вообще, могут быть и другие причины, без профилирования сложно сказать наверняка.

> Вопрос 2: как сделать подгрузку словаря в parse правильно?

Никак. Метод `Backbone.Collection.parse` (как, впрочем, и `Backbone.Model.parse`) должны быть *синхронными* и возвращать результат *сразу*. Как следствие, никаких асинхронных действий (вроде отправки AJAX запроса) там быть не должно. Да, формально вы можете обойти это ограничение, но это не правильно.

А правильно было бы создать отдельную модель/коллекцию для вашего словаря и загружать ее *перед* созданием самой коллекции. После того, как словарь загружен, вы можете передать его коллекции в явном виде и уже потом вызывать `fetch` для коллекции. Тогда, в методе `parse` у вас будут только *синхронные* операции преобразования моделей.

Comment: Кстати, этот подход мне нравится больше. Словарей может стать больше. Их можно хранить в отдельной коллекции. Конечно, структура каждого словаря может быть разная, а хранить модели разной структуры в одной коллекции неправильно, но если знать, что там только словари, которые я получаю один раз при загрузке, то я могу на этой пойти.

Comment: @Mr.Brightside Если словарей мало, то проще создать по модели(коллекции) для каждого из них. Плюс в них же можно скрыть логику отображения и, возможно, какую-то еще специфическую деятельность.

Comment: Логики отображения там нет. Нужны только данные, чтобы по айдишнику делать замену циферки на текст =) Спасибо, принимаю Ваш ответ